# Error Elasticsearch client not compatible with Elasticsearch server?

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, td-agent

I have installed `td-agent` and I am trying to upload data to Elasticsearch. Below is the `td-agent.conf` file:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/rocket/PycharmProjects/EFK/log.json
  pos_file /home/rocket/PycharmProjects/EFK/log.json.pos
  format json
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  tag log
</source>

<match *log*>
  @type elasticsearch
  host 35.171.30.19
  port 9200
  user elastic
  password XXXXXX
  index_name test
</match>
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
2023-01-30 14:13:47 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.15.3 pid=5105 ruby="2.7.6"
2023-01-30 14:13:47 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/opt/td-agent/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/opt/td-agent/bin/fluentd", "--log", "/var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log", "--daemon", "/var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid", "--under-supervisor"]
2023-01-30 14:13:47 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-01-30 14:13:48 +0000 [info]: #0 init worker0 logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-01-30 14:13:48 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="*log*" type="elasticsearch"
2023-01-30 14:13:48 +0000 [error]: #0 config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Using Elasticsearch client 8.4.0 is not compatible for your Elasticsearch server. Please check your using elasticsearch gem version and Elasticsearch server."
2023-01-30 14:13:48 +0000 [error]: Worker 0 finished unexpectedly with status 2
2023-01-30 14:13:48 +0000 [info]: Received graceful stop
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-calyptia-monitoring' version '0.1.3'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '5.2.4'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-flowcounter-simple' version '0.1.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.18.1'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-metrics-cmetrics' version '0.1.2'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-opensearch' version '1.0.8'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.3'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus_pushgateway' version '0.1.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.1'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.4.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '1.7.2'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-sd-dns' version '0.1.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.5'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '1.2.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-utmpx' version '0.5.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '1.5.0'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.15.3'
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type tail
    path "/home/rocket/PycharmProjects/EFK/log.json"
    pos_file "/home/rocket/PycharmProjects/EFK/log.json.pos"
    format json
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    tag "log"
    <parse>
      time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
      @type json
      unmatched_lines 
      time_type string
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match *log*>
    @type elasticsearch
    host "35.179.40.29"
    port 9200
    user "elastic"
    password xxxxxx
    index_name "test"
  </match>
</ROOT>
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.15.3 pid=5116 ruby="2.7.6"
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/opt/td-agent/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/opt/td-agent/bin/fluentd", "--log", "/var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log", "--daemon", "/var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid", "--under-supervisor"]
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: #0 init worker0 logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-01-30 14:13:49 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="*log*" type="elasticsearch"
2023-01-30 14:13:50 +0000 [error]: #0 config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Using Elasticsearch client 8.4.0 is not compatible for your Elasticsearch server. Please check your using elasticsearch gem version and Elasticsearch server."
2023-01-30 14:13:50 +0000 [error]: Worker 0 finished unexpectedly with status 2
2023-01-30 14:13:50 +0000 [info]: Received graceful stop
```

So the error says `error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Using Elasticsearch client 8.4.0 is not compatible for your Elasticsearch server. Please check your using elasticsearch gem version and Elasticsearch server."`

So it's an issue between the Elastic plugin version and Elasticsearch server version. But I am unable to find anywhere which version is supported and how to install it.

Below is how I have installed `td-agent` in Ubuntu 18.04.

`curl -fsSL https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-ubuntu-bionic-td-agent4.sh | sh`

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET -u 'elastic:xxxxx' http://35.179.40.29:9200` ?

Comment: Please refrain from adding `code formatting` to names of software - you've been asked this previously. Don't make work for volunteer editors please by doing your own thing.